# Why doesn't this FOR command delete all files except the one I want to keep?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have the following files in a folder download\gutt_menu_win (from a `dir` command)

```
    27/04/2015  09:02    <DIR>          .
    27/04/2015  09:02    <DIR>          ..
    26/08/2013  01:38           274,218 autorun.csp
    22/04/2013  18:26         2,120,704 autorun.exe
    22/04/2013  18:09            32,038 autorun.ico
    03/11/2009  04:34               350 disclaimer.txt
    22/04/2013  18:26         2,120,704 gutt_v1.0.0.exe
    27/04/2015  09:02               277 list.txt
    05/11/2012  20:57               957 readme.txt
    27/04/2015  08:57    <DIR>          software
    27/04/2015  08:57    <DIR>          website
                   7 File(s)      4,549,248 bytes
                   4 Dir(s)  33,154,744,320 bytes free
```

When I run the following command via a .bat file

```
for %%i in (download\%sku%_menu_win\*.*) do if not %%i == %sku%_v*.exe del %%i
```

It deletes all files in the folder but I want it to delete all files except the gutt_v1.0.0.exe file.

I am feeding the `%sku%` variable into the batch earlier and it is working elsewhere so that doesn't seem the be the issue.
The command also doesn't delete a hidden (autorun.inf) file in the folder but I have corrected that with an additional command:

```
DEL /a:h /q download\%sku%_menu_win\autorun.inf
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The title - "Why does this FOR command delete all files except the one I want to keep?" - implies it's working as you want. It deletes all files except the one you want to keep (according to your title). Is your title correct?

Comment: I don't think you can use [wildcards in if conditions](http://superuser.com/questions/709651/how-to-perform-wildcard-string-comparison-in-batch-file). And is there a reason you don't just extract the file you want to keep to a different directory and the just delete everything?

Comment: I have thought about moving the file out and back again but was just hoping for a solution that didn't require this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use wildcards within IF statements.

A simple solution is to switch to a FOR /F loop that iterates the result of a DIR /B piped to FINDSTR. The /V switch excludes matching strings.

```
pushd "download\%sku%_menu_win"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d^|findstr /v "^%sku%.*\.exe$"'
) do del "%%F"
```

Comment: When I use this, the script goes to the correct directory as specfied in the `pushd` command but I get the following: `| was unexpected at this time` error

Comment: @delprimero - Yes, sorry. I had an error - the pipe must be escaped when used within a command executed via FOR /F. I've edited the answer.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! Is there any way to have this also delete the hidden file or do I still need to use my `DEL` command?

Comment: @delprimero - You could change the DO command to `del /a -s "%%F"`, and it will delete anything that is not a system file (including hidden files).